# Scroll Horizontal al usar row y col de Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-5

No puedo utilizar bien `row` y `col`, me termina provocando scroll de forma horizontal. Busco la forma pero no la encuentro y al final uso `display: flex`.
Saco todo, pongo solo un `h1` y sigue teniendo el scroll horizontal, comienza la falla únicamente al poner `row` y `col`. Estoy usando Bootstrap y solamente hice un `footer` con los derechos reservados, con 2 listas desordenadas

```html
<footer class="bg-warning py-3">
      <section class="row">
        <article class="col-12">
          <h2 class="lead text-white p-4 text-center">
            <b>&copy Todos los derechos reservados</b>
          </h2>
        </article>
        <article class="col-6">
          <ul>
            <li class="mt-2 list-unstyled">
              <a class="text-white link-footer" href="">Contacto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mt-2 list-unstyled">
              <a class="text-white link-footer" href="">¿Quienes somos?</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mt-2 list-unstyled">
              <a class="text-white link-footer" href="">Biblioteca de juegos</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </article>
        <article class="col-6">
          <ul>
            <li class="list-unstyled">
              <a class="link-footer text-white" href="">
                <i class="mt-1 me-3 text-white fa-2x fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                Facebook</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="list-unstyled">
              <a class="link-footer text-white" href=""
                ><i
                  class="mt-1 me-3 text-white fa-2x fa-brands fa-instagram"
                ></i>
                Instagram</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="list-unstyled">
              <a class="link-footer text-white" href=""
                ><i class="mt-1 me-3 text-white fa-2x fa-brands fa-twitter"></i
                >Twitter</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </section>
    </footer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está ocurriendo porque las clases de Bootstrap **row**, **col** y **container/container-fluid** están preparadas para ir de la mano. Un `.row` debe ser siempre hijo directo de un `.container/.container-fluid`, al igual que un `.col` siempre debe serlo de un `.row`.

Las clase `.row` tienen márgenes negativos que son compensados por las clases `container` o `container-fluid`. Si no son compensados se produce el desbordamiento que estás experimentando.

Ejemplo sin contenedor:

```css
.sin-contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="sin-contenedor">
      <p>Sin contenedor</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo con contenedor:

```css
.con-contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="con-contenedor">
        <p>Con contenedor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En el primer ejemplo no estoy usando un contenedor, por lo que se produce el desbordamiento, en el segundo ejemplo si lo estoy usando, no produciéndose.

Si analizas a través del inspector de código de tu navegador las reglas **CSS** que aportan dichas clases de Bootstrap, verás rápidamente a lo que me estoy refiriendo.